# How to check if date passed is in yyyymmdd format and not yyyyddmm?

Tags: shell

I am passing an argument 'bdate' with date as an argument.How to create a function in shell script to check if date passed is in yyyymmdd format and not in 'yyyyddmm'?

Any ideas would be appreciated?

Comment: You can't.  20220102 is valid in either format.  If you want to reject the ones with dd > 12 then it would be helpful to tell us which specific shell you are using. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot solve this in general as yyyddmm with dd between 01 and 12 are valid in both formats.  This gives you a false sense of security.

You can use `date` as @49KWIC explains above, I would, or if you only want to detect the specific issue you can do this:

```
yyyymmdd() {
    case `echo "$1" | cut -b 5-6` in
    01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12)
        return 0;
        ;;
    *)
        return 1;
        ;;
    esac
}

for d in 20220102 20220302 xxxx12xx 20221301 xxxxxxxx x
do
    echo -n "$d ";
    yyyymmdd "$d" && echo valid || echo invalid
done
```

and it outputs:

```
20220102 valid
20220302 valid
xxxx12xx valid
20221301 invalid
xxxxxxxx invalid
x invalid
```